# Output nested JSON array in PHP

Tags: php, json

When I run my PHP script, it generates the JSON that appears below.

Most events happen on the same date but you'll notice that the Kevin Bridges performance has a different array structure to the rest, because there are multiple dates for him.

I'd like to have a `foreach` loop list all those event dates individually, so ultimately I have an unordered list showing all event dates (including nested ones).

**PHP:**

```
$json_link = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$fb_page_id}/events/attending/?fields={$fields}&access_token={$access_token}&since={$since}&limit={$limit}";
$json = file_get_contents($json_link);
$arr = json_decode($json);
var_dump($arr);
```

**JSON (contents of var_dump($arr):**

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(25) "Professor Brian Cox Live!"
      ["start_time"]=>
      string(24) "2019-02-19T18:00:00+0000"
      ["id"]=>
      string(15) "844836785694139"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(11) "Deacon Blue"
      ["start_time"]=>
      string(24) "2018-12-15T18:00:00+0000"
      ["id"]=>
      string(16) "1906293969624796"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(25) "The Australian Pink Floyd"
      ["start_time"]=>
      string(24) "2018-12-01T18:00:00+0000"
      ["id"]=>
      string(15) "992095460928258"
    }
    [3]=>
    object(stdClass)#5 (3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(30) "Jeff Wayne's War of the Worlds"
      ["start_time"]=>
      string(24) "2018-11-30T18:00:00+0000"
      ["id"]=>
      string(15) "127293857967359"
    }
    [4]=>
    object(stdClass)#6 (3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(12) "Nitro Circus"
      ["start_time"]=>
      string(24) "2018-11-21T18:00:00+0000"
      ["id"]=>
      string(16) "1922897747961465"
    }
    [5]=>
    object(stdClass)#7 (4) {
      ["event_times"]=>
      array(17) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#8 (4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(16) "1162283923902012"
          ["start_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-25T18:30:00+0100"
          ["end_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-25T22:30:00+0100"
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#9 (4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(16) "1162283920568679"
          ["start_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-28T18:30:00+0000"
          ["end_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-28T22:30:00+0000"
        }
        [2]=>
        object(stdClass)#10 (4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(16) "1162178570579214"
          ["start_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-27T18:30:00+0100"
          ["end_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-27T22:30:00+0100"
        }
        [3]=>
        object(stdClass)#11 (4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(16) "1162178567245881"
          ["start_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-26T18:30:00+0100"
          ["end_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-26T22:30:00+0100"
        }
        [4]=>
        object(stdClass)#12 (4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(16) "1162150737248664"
          ["start_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-21T18:30:00+0100"
          ["end_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-21T22:30:00+0100"
        }
        [5]=>
        object(stdClass)#13 (4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(16) "1161763073954097"
          ["start_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-17T18:30:00+0100"
          ["end_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-17T22:30:00+0100"
        }
        [6]=>
        object(stdClass)#14 (4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(16) "1161763070620764"
          ["start_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-18T18:30:00+0100"
          ["end_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-18T22:30:00+0100"
        }
        [7]=>
        object(stdClass)#15 (4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(16) "1161179750679096"
          ["start_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-20T18:30:00+0100"
          ["end_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-20T22:30:00+0100"
        }
        [8]=>
        object(stdClass)#16 (4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(16) "1161179747345763"
          ["start_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-19T18:30:00+0100"
          ["end_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-19T22:30:00+0100"
        }
        [9]=>
        object(stdClass)#17 (4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(16) "1161070534023351"
          ["start_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-07T18:30:00+0100"
          ["end_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-07T22:30:00+0100"
        }
        [10]=>
        object(stdClass)#18 (4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(16) "1161070530690018"
          ["start_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-14T18:30:00+0100"
          ["end_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-14T22:30:00+0100"
        }
        [11]=>
        object(stdClass)#19 (4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(16) "1160256300771441"
          ["start_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-13T18:30:00+0100"
          ["end_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-13T22:30:00+0100"
        }
        [12]=>
        object(stdClass)#20 (4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(16) "1160256287438109"
          ["start_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-05T18:30:00+0100"
          ["end_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-05T22:30:00+0100"
        }
        [13]=>
        object(stdClass)#21 (4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(16) "1160256284104776"
          ["start_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-04T18:30:00+0100"
          ["end_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-04T22:30:00+0100"
        }
        [14]=>
        object(stdClass)#22 (4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(16) "1160256280771443"
          ["start_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-06T18:30:00+0100"
          ["end_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-06T22:30:00+0100"
        }
        [15]=>
        object(stdClass)#23 (4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(16) "1160256277438110"
          ["start_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-12T18:30:00+0100"
          ["end_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-12T22:30:00+0100"
        }
        [16]=>
        object(stdClass)#24 (4) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(16) "1160256274104777"
          ["start_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-11T18:30:00+0100"
          ["end_time"]=>
          string(24) "2018-10-11T22:30:00+0100"
        }
      }
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "Kevin Bridges"
      ["start_time"]=>
      string(24) "2018-10-04T18:30:00+0100"
      ["id"]=>
      string(16) "1160256267438111"
    }
  }
}
```

My code for looping is the following, however it doesn't loop through all the individual Kevin Bridges performances:

**PHP:**

```
foreach (array_reverse($arr->data) as $key => $event):

    echo $event->id;
    echo $event->name;
    echo $event->start_time;
    echo '<br>';

endforeach;
```

Comment: So you can't write the foreach? Or what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I should explain. When I write the foreach loop, it skips the Kevin Bridges performance. Will add the code I'm using :-)

Comment: I have added the `foreach` above that I'm using, but this only loops one entry for Kevin Bridges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$fields = "event_times,name,start_time";
$access_token = "*******|********";
$fb_page_id = "thehydro";
$limit = "15";
$since = date('e');
$json_link = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$fb_page_id}/events/attending/?fields={$fields}&access_token={$access_token}&since={$since}&limit={$limit}";
$json = file_get_contents($json_link);
$arr = json_decode($json,true);

function toEventListing($data) {

    $listing = [
        'id' => $data['id'],
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'events' => [],
    ];

    if (empty($data['event_times'])) {
        $listing['events'][] = [
            'id' => $data['id'],
            'start_time' => $data['start_time'],
            'end_time' => null,
            'tickets' => null,
        ];
    } else {
        foreach ($data['event_times'] as $event) {
            $listing['events'][] = [
                'id' => $event['id'],
                'start_time' => $event['start_time'],
                'end_time' => $event['end_time'],
                'tickets' => $event['ticket_uri'],
            ];
        }
    }

    return $listing;
};

$listings = array_map('toEventListing', $arr['data']);

foreach ($listings as $listing) {
    foreach ($listing['events'] as $event) {
        vprintf("INSERT INTO events (id, fbpid, fbid, name, start, end, tickets) VALUES (null, %s, %s, '%s', '%s', '%s');\n", [
            $listing['id'],
            $event['id'],
            $listing['name'],
            date('c', strtotime($event['start_time'])),
            empty($event['end_time']) ? null : date('c', strtotime($event['end_time'])),
            empty($event['tickets']) ? null : $event['tickets'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
```

This will solve the error and give you the array you want.

**Edit for new question**

```
foreach ($arr['data'] as  $event):

    echo $event['id'];
    echo $event['name'];
    echo $event['start_time'];
    echo '<br>';

endforeach;
```

try a simple foreach for starting. This one will go through your array fields you want.

**New Edit**

```
$array=Array
(



    0=> Array
        (
            'name' => 'Nitro Circus',
            'start_time' => '2018-11-21T18:00:00+0000',
            'id' => '1922897747961465'
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            'event_times' => Array
                (
                    0 => Array
                        (
                            'id' => 1162283923902012,
                            'start_time' => '2018-10-25T18:30:00+0100',
                            'end_time' => '2018-10-25T22:30:00+0100',
                            'ticket_uri' => 'bit.ly/2mSdNh1'
                        )


                ),

            'name' => 'Kevin Bridges',
            'start_time' => '2018-10-04T18:30:00+0100',
            'id' => '1160256267438111'
        )

);


foreach ($array as  $event):

    echo $event['id'];
    echo $event['name'];
    echo $event['start_time'];
    echo '<br>';

endforeach;
```

So i created a mock array same as the one you gave me and access it with the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I replaced it and now get this Warning `array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array`.

Comment: `array_reverse($arr['data']) ` try this. You have an array now.

Comment: So it should be `foreach (array_reverse($arr['data']) as $key => $event):`?

Comment: Thanks for your update. This still just lists 1 entry for Kevin Bridges, rather than all his performances. Any ideas why?

Comment: I get the results for Kevin Bridges when i parse the array in the above away. That's weird. Basically it's in the 5 place of the array so i retrieve everything as it should.

Comment: Very weird : ( It just shows one entry for Kevin Bridges for me. Can you show me your full code?

Comment: Aaaah. I think yours works because it works differently to my JSON pull from Facebook.

Comment: I got the structure from the array you gave me but i hope it can be helpful the way i access the fields in order to make it work for you also. Can you tell me where it "breaks" in Kevin's record?

Answer (score 1):

its simple as it has nested array, u have to iterate twice

```
Json node has these attribute/node 
name
start_time
id
event_times[][id,star_time,end_time]
```

Following should work

```
$json_link = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$fb_page_id}/events/attending/?fields={$fields}&access_token={$access_token}&since={$since}&limit={$limit}";
$json = file_get_contents($json_link);
$arr = json_decode($json);

foreach ($arr->data as $attende):
    echo "\nName:".$attende->name."\n";
    echo "Events \n";
    if(isset($attende->event_times)){
      foreach ($attende as $key => $event):
        echo $event->id;
        echo $event->name;
        echo $event->start_time;
        echo '<br>';
      endforeach;
    }



endforeach;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think it's *quite* right however. In the second `foreach` loop I get the following notice: `Trying to get property of non-object in`. It doesn't output the data.